# Ajax GET with notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have been looking for an example, but I must be using the wrong search phrase as I haven't found one.

I have a "list" that is displayed in a partial view, and am generating an Ajax Action link with the following code:

```
    <td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Add", "AddClient", new { id = consignee.nId, mailingListId = consignee.MailingListId },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            LoadingElementId = "loading2",
            LoadingElementDuration = 750
        })
   </td>
```

This call works but I want a notification to appear at the top of the screen that says "Record Added".

The current style moves all of the information down, and looks odd.

```
<body>
   <div id="loading2" style="display:none">
     <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Added!</strong>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I want a piece of text to just popup at the top of the screen, over the logos that are there and not move any of the currently HTML down.

If anyone can help I would really appreciate ti,
TIA

Comment: You can just style the element so its absolutely positioned

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8cd53Ln/1/) for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a css class to your notification div and position it absolute and specify the `top` position. You may initially hide it (With another css class) and update the visibility when you want to show the notification.

```
<div id="loading2" class="alwaysTop hidden">
     <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Added!</strong>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the css will be

```
.alwaysTop
{
  position : absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}
.hidden
{
  display:none;
}
```

This will add your div to top right corner of the page. Whenever you want to show the notification message, remove the hiddenClass.

```
$("#loading2").removeClass("hidden");
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/jusiyugebi/edit?html,css,js,output) is a working sample.

If you wan't to do more custom stuff, It is always good to write HTML markup (without Ajax.ActioLink method) and control the ajax functionality yourself.

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddClient","Client", 
    new {id = consignee.nId, mailingListId = consignee.MailingListId },
                                                new {@id="addLink"})
```

And javascript to handle the click event of this link

```
$(function(){
  $("#addLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr("href"),function(res){
       if(res.status==="success")
       {
         $("#loading2").removeClass("hidden");
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Assuming you have an action method called `AddClient` inside `ClientController`

```
public ActionResult AddClient(int id, int mailingListId)
{
  // do something 
  return Json(new { status="success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: This works really well, but the comment still appears at the top of the screen. If I have 2 or 3 pages of data, and I add a record at the bottom I don't see the alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel on doing notifications, you could use a jquery plugin for notification. Check out [Notify.js](https://notifyjs.com/)